# Position cursor at beginning of text on edit mode

Tags: fields, text

I'm working with assistive technology, a page reading device for blind and low sight people. Problem I'm having is when they go to edit a page, Account for example, and they tab to text box (long text), the cursor is winding up at the very end of the text entry.

This is a problem as the assitive page reader can't 'see' that there's text to read out loud and its critical information a user needs to know.

Anyone know of a way to position the cursor at the beginning of the text field when in edit? I can only get it to show up at the very end of text.

Many thanks,

Paul

Comment: Could you provide more context? E.g. is this a record page? Classic or Lightning? Screenshots?

Comment: It is an Account record page, and a long text field a user can type in special intructions realated to the account. We're using Lightning.

Comment: Interesting, it does seem that short text fields select the whole thing when you tab, and long text fields jump to the end. Maybe because they assume when you are editing, say, a Comments field, you will want to append to it rather than replace it. In Lightning standard pages there is really nothing you can do to customize/fudge this behaviour. Windows users can type Ctrl-Home to jump to the start of the text field. It might be worth hunting around on the Trailblazer Community for someone at Salesforce responsible for accessibility.

Comment: I'm trimmed the field down to 200 characters and now the entire text in the field is highlighted when tabbing into the field. The screen reader can now read it.
Problem solved. thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool good to know! That being said it might be worth also opening a support ticket to the screen reader software company. It's not an uncommon use case that tabbing into a field drops the cursor at the end (e.g. because you are meant to append not replace). If the screen reader is treating that like a blank they should consider improving that behaviour. Even here on StackExchange, if you tab away from a comment field and then tab back into it, you'll see the same end-of-field behaviour.

Comment: Well, ironically enough, I am the new SFDC Admin at 'the screen reader software company' :) We make devices and software that help blind and low sight people live better lives. I need to wrap up this implementation and then can see if our product manager will give me some time to chat about SFDC and our products abilities.

Comment: Oh very interesting! I would be curious if other competing screen reader products have the same issue with cursor-at-end fields. If not, then it's definitely reportable as a bug.